# Get the value of a lists in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying out a homework where I am required to set up a nested dictionary with lists. The user needs to input the category  and view the available books in the category and view the price of each book.

```
    # List of Books
    Category = {
        "Fiction": {
        "Rapunzel": 3.00,
        "Cindrella": 4.00
        },
        "Non-Fiction": {
        "Life of Khans": 7.00,
        "History of Rome": 18.00
        },
        "Manga": {
        "Naruto": 2.00,
        "Attack on Titan": 3.00
        }
   }


   def enquiry_system():
       print("Welcome to Alice Bookstore\n")
       print("These are the available categories:\n")
       for item in Category:
           print(item)

       user_category = input("\nPlease select a category to view the list 
                              of books: ")
       if user_category in Category:
           print(f"\nBook Title: {', '.join(Category[user_category])}")
       user_book = input("\nPlease select your choice of the book: ")
           if user_book in Category[user_category]:
              price = user_category[user_book]
              print(f'\n The price is:{price}')
```

Now at the last line of the code, how do i view the price of the book?
I do not know on how to get the value of a key in a list within nested dictionary.

The error I am getting is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:/Python/OOP/Main.py", line 33, in <module>
          enquiry_system()
        File "D:/Python/OOP/Main.py", line 30, in enquiry_system
          print(Category[user_category[user_book]])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Did you try to run this code? It seems reasonable. What exactly was the problem?

Comment: The error I am getting is this 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/OOP/Main.py", line 33, in <module>
    enquiry_system()
  File "D:/Python/OOP/Main.py", line 30, in enquiry_system
    print(Category[user_category[user_book]])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: The error code and the posted code are not the same

Comment: I tried  price = Category[user_category[user_book]] and got the updated error but now solved after changing to 
price = Category[user_category][user_book]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second to last line, you're looking up the index in your string as opposed to the dictionary you do the if statement on.

```
  price = Category[user_category][user_book]
```

Comment: How could i repeat the function if the user enters invalid input?

Comment: I had figured it out by adding while True: before the line user_category = input

Answer (score 0):

user_category is just a string of whatever the user entered. To get to your price data you have to reference the dictionary Category. Here is an example code:

```
price = Category[user_category][user_book]
```